# Integrate SuccessFactors and S4HANA using S4 SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana, sap-successfactors

Currently we are referring [https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/%20blogs.) blogs for our side by side extensibility use cases.

We are trying to create a scenario for Building a side by side extensibility application to integrate successfactor and S/4 hana system using S4 SDK.

We couldn't find any blogs, sample code implementation to integrate successfactors and hana system.We found the below relevant blog.

[https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/tree/master/Employee-Browser-Neo](http://.https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/tree/master/Employee-Browser-Neo)

But we couldn't understand the detailed scenario and output of this GitHub sample code.
It would be great if someone help us with blogs/urls/code.

Comment: If Daniel's answer solved the issue, please mark it as 'accepted' to signal other users on StackOverflow that this question is answered. You can do so by clicking the green checkmark next to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

currently, there is no dedicated material for SuccessFactors. However, I recommend the following blog post:
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/

It describes how to generate the virtual data model for a custom OData service.
You can use the same approach to connect to SuccessFactors.

As input for the generator, you would use the metadata file provided by SuccessFactors. You can for example access the $metadata path of the OData service.

Afterwards, can can use the generated Java classes to access the SuccessFactors API.

To connect to SuccessFactors, create a destination for your SuccessFactors system, e.g. called `SuccessFactorsODataEndpoint`. That works locally as environment variable or in the destination service on SAP Cloud Platform as explained here: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/

In the execute method in the virtual data model you can define which destination to use:
`.execute(new ErpConfigContext("SuccessFactorsODataEndpoint"))`